# Close Variable Name Webbrowser from Different Location Using Timer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, timer, browser, webbrowser-control

How to Close Variable Name Webbrowser from Different Location in VB.Net Code? to clarify I've posted a sample code blow with the question:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim TimeResultC = 9999999999
Dim Time1C = DateTime.Parse(TimeOfDay)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim WebPage(10)
    WebPage(0) = "http://www.mekdam.com/"
    WebPage(1) = "http://www.mekdam.com/gallery.php"
    WebPage(2) = "http://www.mekdam.com/money_bills_million_dollar.php"
    WebPage(3) = "http://www.mekdam.com/certificate_of_authenticity.php"
    WebPage(4) = "http://www.mekdam.com/wallpapers.php"
    Dim LastWebNumber = 4
    Dim jjjjRandon As Integer
    Dim wwwwA = 1
    Do While wwwwA <= 5
        jjjjRandon = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * LastWebNumber))
        Navigate(jjjjRandon, WebPage(jjjjRandon))
        wwwwA += 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim Time2C = DateTime.Parse(TimeOfDay)
    Time2C = DateTime.Parse(TimeOfDay)
    TimeResultC = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Time1C, Time2C)
    Label1.Text = TimeResultC
    If Label1.Text > 10 Then
        ' HOW TO CLOSE OPEN WEBSITES ONE BY ONE FROM THIS CODE'S LOCATION??
        MessageBox.Show("pass 10 seconds")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

and the Model code is below:

```
Module MekdamBrowser
Sub Navigate(ByVal WebSF As Double, ByVal Website As String)
    Dim frmNew As New Form
    frmNew.Show()
    frmNew.Height = 600
    frmNew.Width = 1200
    Dim MekdamBrowser As New WebBrowser
    MekdamBrowser.Name = "WebBrowser" & WebSF
    frmNew.Controls.Add(MekdamBrowser)
    MekdamBrowser.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 30)
    MekdamBrowser.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1160, 520)
    MekdamBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    Dim Label1 As New Label()
    frmNew.Controls.Add(Label1)
    Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
    Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Label1.AutoSize = True
    Label1.Text = MekdamBrowser.Name & " - " & Website
    MekdamBrowser.Navigate(Website)
    While MekdamBrowser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The use of Application.DoEvents is proof of ignorance of event-driven software.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, couldn't have said it better. Goggling "Application.DoEvents" comes up with ["Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx) on the 2nd place, and yet people keep using and abusing it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things  you will need to add a close Function to your MekdamBrowser Module and populate the Name Property of your frmNew. After doing so you can search your programs FormCollection to find your WebPages and close them.

Here is the modified Module.

```
Module MekdamBrowser
    Sub Navigate(ByVal WebSF As Double, ByVal Website As String)
        Dim frmNew As New Form
        frmNew.Name = "frmNew"
        frmNew.Show()
        frmNew.Height = 600
        frmNew.Width = 1200
        Dim MekdamBrowser As New WebBrowser
        MekdamBrowser.Name = "WebBrowser" & WebSF
        frmNew.Controls.Add(MekdamBrowser)
        MekdamBrowser.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 30)
        MekdamBrowser.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1160, 520)
        MekdamBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        Dim Label1 As New Label()
        frmNew.Controls.Add(Label1)
        Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
        Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Label1.AutoSize = True
        Label1.Text = MekdamBrowser.Name & " - " & Website
        MekdamBrowser.Navigate(Website)
        While MekdamBrowser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub
    Function CloseWebsite() As Boolean
        If Not IsNothing(Application.OpenForms("frmNew")) Then
            Application.OpenForms("frmNew").Close()
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Modified Timer Tick Event

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim Time2C = DateTime.Parse(TimeOfDay)
    Time2C = DateTime.Parse(TimeOfDay)
    TimeResultC = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Time1C, Time2C)
    Label1.Text = TimeResultC
    If Label1.Text > 10 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = CloseWebsite() 'Use return value to stop timer if no
                                        'more webpages are open
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's sad to see `Application.DoEvents()` is still there, inside a busy waiting loop.